lifetime of static variable inside a class and change its value
class B{
public:
        static int Setdec(int val, bool bGet = false) {
            static int dec = 0;
            if (!bGet) dec = val;
            return dec;
        }
        static int Getdec() {
            return Setdec(0, true);
        }
        static int dec() {
            return Getdec();
        }
    };
int main(){
       B::Setdec(10);
       printf("The value of static member is %d", B::dec());
       return 0;
}

in the line B::Setdec(10);, it seems a static variable dec was created within in the class B and thus it became a static member of class B. Its value is 10. But why in the line printf("The value of static member is %d", B::dec());,  its value is still 10? It is not changed to 0 again?

Let's get terminology straight. dec is not a "static member" at all. It is a local static variable inside of a static member function of a class. Thus, dec is initialized the first time that static member function B::Setdec() is called. The line static int dec = 0; declares and initializes that variable. But it doesn't mean the variable becomes a member of the class, it's just a local static variable inside of a function.

Try with a free function first to see how static variable initialization works. Forget about static members for a while. Once you get that part correct, take a look back at this case. The meaning of static in C++ is loaded and the statics in your code do not mean the same thing.

You ask why it's not changed to 0 again, but why it should change to zero? You are calling B::dec(), which in turn calls B::Getdec(), which in turn calls B::Setdec(0, true), which, when executed, first, passes the line static int dec = 0;. That line does nothing this time, because a local static variable will be initialized only once (the first time the function is called). Next, because this time bGet is true, it doesn't execute the assignment dec = val;. So the value remains unchanged.

@heapunderrun, thanks! Got it!

Also (just in case you assume otherwise), note that in C++, nothing can dynamically "become a member of a class" at runtime: all class members (i.e., member variables and member functions) are declared in the source code before it gets compiled, and the definition of the class stays the same throughout the lifetime of the program. You cannot add/remove members to/from a class by executing some code etc.

Also make sure you do not put that code in a header file, the initialization of the static must happen in a C++ source file. static before your function declaration means the function is part of the namespace of the class, but will not have access to any of the member variables (it is in the end a free function just within the class namespace). The static for the local variable means it will be initialized once on first use. And then reused in all later function calls.
